# how to identify which tap gesture recognizer is called?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have 2 UIImageView, named "artistImage" and "albumImage", each one contains 1 tap gesture and all the gestures are connected to 1 @IBAction, named "artistImageTap". Those tap gestures are drag from object library and place over my ImageView.

Storyboard - Code
[image]

My app have a list of artists, albums and songs, when a song is tapped, the app moves to this view and display its details. If I click the add button, the app moves to this view but this time all the text fields are editable, the images are default and user can tap them to select image from library to create new song.

My problem is I don't know how to identify which UIImageView is tapped. As you can see in the picture, I tried picker.restorationIdentifier but it always returns nil.

```
@IBAction func artistImageTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

    // Only allow photos to be picked, not taken.
    imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    // Make sure ViewController is notified when the user picks an image.
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    // The info dictionary may contain multiple representations of the image. You want to use the original.
    guard let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage else {
        fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
    }

    // Set photoImageView to display the selected image.
    if picker.restorationIdentifier == "artistImage" {
        artistImage.image = selectedImage
    } else {
        albumImage.image = selectedImage
    }
    // Dismiss the picker.
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Every help is appreciated!!

Comment: Nobody even knows how you are creating a gesture recognizer.

Comment: use `sender.view` and setup a `tag` in your `UIImageView`, after that you can use `sender.view.tag` as identifier

Comment: @ElTomato I added them by dragging from object library. Sorry for not mention that!

Comment: @ReinierMelian I tried to setup tag for my view, scrollview, content view, even the ImageView, but none of them showed up when I used sender.view.tag

Comment: use `debugPrint(sender.view)` and let me know what prints @hell2809

Comment: @ReinierMelian 

"Optional(<UIImageView: 0x7fabb2f15410; frame = (245 490; 90 90); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 1; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x604000250d70>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60400023d0a0>>)"

NOW the tag is "1". Feel like they are trying to drive me nuts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add tag to both UIImageView from storyboard.
  like artistImage = 1001 and albumImage = 1002

  ```
  @IBAction func artistImageTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

  if sender.view?.tag == 1001 {

      selectedTag = 1001

  } else if sender.view?.tag == 1002 {

     selectedTag = 1002

  }

  let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

  // Only allow photos to be picked, not taken.
  imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
  // Make sure ViewController is notified when the user picks an image.
  imagePickerController.delegate = self
  present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
  ```
- store selected tag in one variable.
- now you can check which on image user have tapped with `selectedTag` variable

Comment: @hell2809 There is no doubt that this question is helpful. but it is bad practice to play with tag. so instead of that Create IBOutlet of Tap Gesture object just like you create IBAction. and compare that IBOutlet with `sender`  object to be more clear :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all set tags for tap gestures when you are applying it on     images.

```
tapGestureArtistImage.tag = 0;
tapGestureAlbumImage.tag = 1;
```

then send tap gesture as parameters in `artistImageTap` method

```
- (void) artistImageTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
  if(sender.tag == 0)
  {
    // artistImage tapped
  }
  else if (sender.tag == 1)
  {
    // albumImage tapped
  }
}
```

Comment: Found my way, similar as yours! Thanks!